# File path or file location for Java - new file()

Tags: java, file-io, filepath, readxml, file-location

I have the following structure for my project.

In Eclipse:

```
myPorjectName
  src
    com.example.myproject
        a.java
    com.example.myproject.data
        b.xml
```

In `a.java`, I want to read `b.xml` file. How can I do that? Specifically, in `a.java`, I used the following code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("data/b.xml"));
```

This code cannot find `b.xml`. However, if I change the path to `src/com/example/myproject/data/b.xml` then it works. The current location seems to be in the root of my project file.

But I see other people's examples, **if `b.xml` and `a.java` are in the same folder, then we can directly use `new File("b.xml")`.** But I try putting `b.xml` in the same folder of `a.java` rather than putting in the sub folder, but it still **does not work**.  If this works, then in my case, I should be able to use `new File("data/b.xml")`, right? I really do not understand why this is not working.

Comment: It's most likely going to be more like `getClass().getResourceAsInputStream("/com/example/myproject/data/b.xml");`

Comment: It's not working because your **default directory (that java is executing from)** is `myPorjectName` it's not in `myproject`

Comment: xagyg and MadProgrammer 's comments make me understand why I was doing it wrong. Thank you guys. The following answer makes me learn something more.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If it is already in the classpath and in the same package, use

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("b.xml");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

OR , read it as an `InputStream`:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("b.xml");
```

Inside a `static` method, you can use

```
InputStream in = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("b.xml");
```

If your file is not in the same package as the class you are trying to access the file from, then you have to give it relative path starting with `'/'`.

```
ex : InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream
           ("/resources/somex.cfg.xml");which is in another jar resource folder
```

Comment: I thinks this is the best way!

Comment: what if it is not in the same package? in my example, a.java is in com.example.myproject. b.xml is in com.example.myproject.data.

Comment: @user1387727 The use a fully qualified path ie `"/com/example/myproject/data/b.xml"` instead...

Comment: In my case, I am trying to read a xml file using: URL url = getClass().getResource("b.xml"); Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File(url.getPath())); Lets assume a.java and b.xml are in the same folder. It does not work. 
I print out url.getPath(), I found that the path starts from /c:/.../.../../myproject/bin/com/../../b.xml. 
Actually the code: docBuilder.parse (new File(url.getPath())) does not like the full file path. If I manually typed the file path: docBuilder.parse (new File("bin/com/../../b.xml")), then it works.
Do you know what I can do instead of manually typing the file path?

Comment: The first one will only work if the JAR or WAR file has been exploded, or there wasn't one in the first place, only a directory system of .class files.