# Text file not found throwing exception

Tags: java, arrays

I am sure there is something really stupid I am missing, but for some reason I am getting an "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException" error even though my input.txt file is located within the package. Any help would be great!

Code for the scanner:

```
File file = new File("input.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
Company c = new Company();
String input = inputFile.nextLine();
```

Complete class code:

```
package SimpleJavaAssignment;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class Company
{
  ArrayList<Department> deptList = new ArrayList<Department>();

  public Department checkDepartment(String name)
  {
    for(Department dept: deptList)
    {
      if(dept.getName().equals(name))
      {
      return dept;
      }
    }
    Department d = new Department(name);
    deptList.add(d);
    return d;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    System.out.println ("This program will compile and display the stored employee data.");


    File file = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    Company c = new Company();
    String input = inputFile.nextLine();



    while(inputFile.hasNextLine() && input.length() != 0)
    {

      String[] inputArray = input.split(" ");
      Department d = c.checkDepartment(inputArray[3]);
      d.newEmployee(Integer.parseInt(inputArray[2]), inputArray[0] + " " + inputArray[1], d);
      input = inputFile.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.printf("%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %n", "DEPARTMENT", "EMPLOYEE NAME", "EMPLOYEE AGE",
          "IS THE AGE A PRIME");
    for(Department dept:c.deptList)
    {
      ArrayList<Employee> empList = dept.getEmployees();
      for(Employee emp: empList)
      {
      emp.printInfo();
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: put it outside your src folder

Comment: If I put it outside the source folder, will I not have to code in the entire path, which would change when I share the program?

Comment: Kevin, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313260/file-path-or-file-location-for-java-new-file .

Comment: You are referring to a bare file name with no path, so the program will look in the _current working directory_ which is _not necessarily_ the same as the directory where the jar file is. It depends on how exactly you invoke your java program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new File("input.txt");` will seek for the file in the same location of the jar being executed. Since you state the file is in the same package of the class, you should use [`Class#getResource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) that returns an `URL`. Then, call [`URL#getFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getFile--) to retrieve the String with the full path of the file.

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("input.txt").getFile());
```

Since you're executing this code in a `static` method, replace `getClass` by `ClassName.class`:

```
File file = new File(Company.class.getResource("input.txt").getFile());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried that and I get the following error.   "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object"

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem has nothing to do with your looking in the right or wrong place for your file (although that might be a problem later), no your current problem is that you're not handling the exception that the compiler is complaining of. When reading a File and using it with a Scanner, you need to either put the code that throws the exception in a try/catch block or have your method throw the exception. If you haven't read the [exception tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) yet, please do yourself and us a favor and read it.

Comment: Just fixed that too. Now dealing with visibility of the "Scanner inputFile;" which is no longer visible past the try/catch.