# Java File Reading: Have to enter full path

Tags: java, file, path, filenotfoundexception

```
package files;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class file {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException {

            File file = new File("txtfile.txt");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(input.nextLine());
            }

    }

}
```

Where it says file.txt I have to enter the full file path. All tutorials I watch do not have to do this.

Comment: This may also help answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313260/file-path-or-file-location-for-java-new-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah! `File file = new File("txtfile.txt");` `txtfile.txt` is a path to your file that you want to read. Provide the path where file is like "C:\Users\me\Desktop\txtfile.txt" if the file is not in the same directory where your java file is. After you compile the java file a .class file is created it that .class file is also created in the same folder it will work with.

`File file = new File("txtfile.txt");` and you don't need to specify the full path.

If not you then you have to provide the absolute file path like above.

Comment: @SirStrategic I believe Maseed is saying that if your file is not in the working directory, then you have to include the whole path. Otherwise you can just to `text.txt`

Comment: Oh.... thanks for that.... But yes, text.txt is in the same directory as the java class.

Comment: `text.txt` should be there where the file `file.class` is created, otherwise you have to provide an absolute `path` to your file.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't enter the path it won't compile and show error.
To set a path..

Open the command prompt and it show something like this
 C:user>admin
You need to change it and point it your program saved location (use cd for change it)

Then type path="

And go to localdisc C: and open programfile->java->jdk->bin

Then save the path at above 
      Which is something like c:/programfile/java/jdk1. 0./bin

Save and copy it in front of path="c:/programfile/java/jdk1. 0./bin";

Then press enter

Then compile the program using javac filename. Java

And run using java filename